# Cognito Contact List Android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I am making an image messaging app and would like to use Cognito for user management and the contact list. So I would need to access Cognito to search and add other users. Is this possible as I can't find any information online? If not, what are some other methods that can be used within AWS?